# Issue in creating Pagination in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use Pagination functionality provided by Laravel. Functionality works correctly for 1st page. However, pagination is not working for subsequent pages.

It is raising an error "Array to String Conversion" while echoing $tableData. Below is my code snippet of view.

```
<tbody>
  @foreach ($tableData as $d)
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{$d->ItemMake}}</td>
    <td>{{$d->Item}}</td>
    <td>{{$d->style}}</td>
    <td>{{$d->Price}}</td>
    <td>{{$d->ItemValue}}</td>
  </tr>
 @endforeach
  <tr>
   <td>
    <?php       
        echo $tableData;
     ?>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

while using "{{$tableData}}" , its throwing the error,
Error : "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

while using "{!! $tableData !!}" , its throwing the error, Error : Array to string conversion

Comment: Where's your pagination code?

Comment: If `$tableData` is a Query builder with Pagination applied(`$query->paginate(10)`) then you can use `render` method to draw pagination like this `{!! $tableData->render()  !!}` and the error is not because of Pagination, it's because you are trying to print an Array with Blade Engine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in pagination.

You can't echo array like string with `{!! $tableData !!}` or `{{ $tableData }}` or `echo $tableData;`

To display contents of an array you should use `foreach` loop or `$tableData[0]` to display first element of that array, for example. Also you can use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`dd()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-dd) functions if you just want to look what's inside of an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to echo pagination links for next pages.

Change

```
echo $tableData;
```

to

```
{{ $tableData->links }}
```

and read [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#displaying-pagination-results).